# Difference Between Predicted Mean Response and Prediction of Future Observation

Tags: regression, linear-model

I'm reading *Linear Models with R, 2nd Ed.,* by Julian Faraway, and he says something puzzling in Chapter 4 on page 51:

> There are two kinds of predictions made from regression models. One is a predicted mean response and the other is a prediction of a future observation. To make the distinction clear, suppose we have built a regression model that predicts the rental price of houses in a given area based on predictors such as the number of bedrooms and closeness to a major highway. There are two kinds of predictions that can be made for a given $x_0$:
>
> 1. Suppose a specific house comes on the market with characteristics $x_0.$ Its rental price will be $x_0^T\beta+\varepsilon.$ Since $E\varepsilon=0,$ the predicted price is $x_0^T\hat\beta,$ but in assessing the variance of this prediction, we must include the variance of $\varepsilon.$
> 2. Suppose we ask the question - "What would a house with characteristics $x_0$ rent for on average?" This selling price is $x_0^T\beta$ and is again predicted by $x_0^T\hat\beta$ but now only the variance in $\hat\beta$ needs to be taken into account.

Note: I think it only fair to ignore the distinction between selling and renting. That distinction is not the author's main point, here, clearly.

Another note: As this is not a homework problem, I am going to leave off the `self-study` tag.

Final note: this question says nothing about "forecasting", so the questions on Stats.SE concerning forecasting are not relevant.

**My Question:** Why can we ignore the variance of $\varepsilon$ in the prediction-of-mean problem (2.), but not the prediction-of-future-observation problem (1.)? I'm also not entirely sure I understand the difference between these two predictions. If you could please clarify that difference, I would be most grateful.

[EDIT] Apparently, predicting a future value corresponds to a *prediction interval*, while predicting a mean value corresponds to a *confidence interval.*

Comment: The duplicate is one of the top hits on a [site search about confidence and prediction intervals](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=prediction+confidence+interval*+score%3A5).  Some of the other hits look informative, too.

Comment: I don't understand why my question was closed: the post said nothing about confidence intervals. Is that really what the question is about, and I don't know it?

Comment: "What would a house with characteristics x0 rent for on average?" This selling price is xT0β and is again predicted by xT0β^ but now only the variance in β^ needs to be taken into account" implicitly describes a confidence interval for the selling price.  Regardless, your quotations are clearly trying to distinguish confidence intervals from prediction intervals and everything written about that subject here helps answer your question.

Comment: Huh. This is starting to get annoying. I already knew the difference between CIs and PIs! This author is British - I wonder if they just use different terminology across the pond. Wouldn't be the first time.

Comment: Their terminology looks standard.  "Predicted mean response" refers to a *property* of the model and "prediction of a future observation" refers to a *random variable.*  Therein is the crux of the distinction between confidence intervals and prediction intervals, respectively.